# syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: laravel-5.1

I am using laravel5.0 on centos 6.9, when I try to run php artisan migarate , getting error PHP Parse error:

```
syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /root/.local/share/Trash/files/keystone_laravel.2/laravel/artisan on line 3
```

please anyone help

Answer (score 1):

Change the version of your php for L5.0 you need to install a

PHP >= 5.4, PHP < 7

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Laravel5.4 and CentOS7.4, and PHP5.4 pre-installed into the system, but I installed php7.0 manually by source-code without link it to **/usr/bin** so when I run **php artisan schedule:run**, it actually run the command with php5.4, and of course I get the same error. So I link php7.0 to **/usr/bin** to make it as default php, then I fixed it.